# Abort crash on android

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, crash, android-11

I am getting below crash after upgrading Android SDK to 30

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.asda.android <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000051010  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #00  pc 00000000006d7c3c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+668)
  #00  pc 000000000001595c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 0000000000014f8c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+364)
  #00  pc 00000000002922fc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::AssertNoPendingException() const+1536)
  #00  pc 000000000031f2a0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artStringBuilderAppend+116)
  #00  pc 00000000002d7e18  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_string_builder_append+56)
  #00  pc 0000000000a74df8  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$createFrameCompleteCallback$4$ViewRootImpl+184)
  #00  pc 0000000000a51d3c  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onFrameComplete+108)
  #00  pc 00000000002cdd64  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 000000000043a59c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+880)
  #00  pc 00000000005b20b0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+300)
  #00  pc 00000000006e85b0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+120)
  #00  pc 000000000073d9a0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::FrameCompleteWrapper::onFrameComplete(long)+156)
  #00  pc 0000000000616d2c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+1724)
  #00  pc 000000000061573c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c1671e787f244890c877724752face20+596)
  #00  pc 000000000062b138  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+156)
  #00  pc 000000000062aea4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+84)
  #00  pc 00000000000120a8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+260)
  #00  pc 0000000000011960  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+404)
  #00  pc 00000000000b2fd0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+264)
  #00  pc 0000000000052834  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

I was not getting this crash before sdk migration to android 30